# PHP remove decimal places from a numbers inside string

Tags: php, string

I have a string variable as below

```
$str=' <p class="old-price">               
            <span class="price" id="old-price-3043">
                €1,073.55                </span>
        </p>

                        <p class="special-price">                   
            <span class="price" id="product-price-3043">
                €742.98                </span>                   
                                </p>';
```

I need to remove decimal places from above string to show as below

```
  $str=' <p class="old-price">               
            <span class="price" id="old-price-3043">
                €1,073                </span>
        </p>

                        <p class="special-price">                   
            <span class="price" id="product-price-3043">
                €742               </span>                   
                                </p>';
```

How can I do this using PHP?

Comment: [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: `preg_replace('~\.\d+~', '', $str);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to remove the period and any numeric sequence after it:

```
$str = $str=' <p class="old-price">               
        <span class="price" id="old-price-3043">
            €1,073.55                </span>
    </p>

                    <p class="special-price">                   
        <span class="price" id="product-price-3043">
            €742.98                </span>                   
                            </p>';
$no_decimals = preg_replace('~\.\d+~', '', $str);
```